# Подключить стили и скрипты Node.JS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Доброго всем времени суток!

У меня есть ряд вопросов по Node.js. Пожалуйста, помоги стать просветленным :)

1) Я не понимаю как Node будет работать на реальном хостинге. 
На компьютере я создаю ведь локальный сервер (с помощью http.createServer и потом server.listen(ПОРТ) ).

2) Я не понимаю как в сервере локальном\в интернете подключить CSS. 
2.1 Делаю сервер, указываю index.html, а как указать другие связанные страницы и стили - не знаю.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. Буду благодарен. Если можно, то киньте плюсом ссылочку на исходники, потому что для меня продуктивнее учиться по коду, а не по словам в книгах.

P.S. Я бы рад всё загуглить, но трафика осталось 800 МБ на 15 дней. Дача, она такая...

Comment: я сам недавно начал с ним работать, но как я понял, если ты запускаешь index.html через сервер, то он как бы делает запросы к файлам на сервер(html,css) и на сервере ты указываешь, если приходит такой то запрос (/css/main.css) отдать файл html, но сейчас там есть хороший модуль express и ты указываешь в нем папку всх своих ресурсов и он сам считывает такие запросы и отдает файлы с указанной директории

Comment: Спасибо, буду учить express. А по каким ресурсам учил? @Horchynskyi

Comment: да там толком учить не надо просто разок подключить и понять как работает) по видео любому где используется это модуль)

Comment: @Horchynskyi , а ты работал с формами  (<form> которые) ?

Comment: да но там больше socket.io использовал) а что интересует?

Comment: @Horchynskyi , у меня есть простой сайт на хостинге (на котором я тренируюсь в WEB), там есть форма. Нужно просто обработать форму, которая посылает запрос методом POST. Я уже запутался как это делать. То ли с помощью Node, то ли с помощью чистого JS (функции написать), то ли с помощью BodyParse...Помоги разобраться, пожалуйста, если не трудно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62631/discussion-between-dzukaev-and-horchynskyi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привет.

На хостинге оно работать не будет. Исключительно на vps.

Причина - node.js сам себе сервер.

**Ответы:**

1) В production обычно на 8080 порту поднимается сервер node.js. На 80ом порту висит nginx который проксирует его.

2) Воспользуйтесь **express**. Он сильно упростит Вам жизнь. В частности, Вы сможете прозрачно указать директорию для статики и получить понятные пути подключения.

Ссылка на исходники - github.com/vpotseluyko/school30

К сожалению, это реальный проект с системой сборки и прочего.